# Problem with tinyMCE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

These are my problems:

1. The tinyMCE show a nice textbox area with editor, but when i select bold, italics ,align options which add class to my content don´t apply the format.
2. I am using **simple modal** JQuery plugin. When I display the popup the text areas don´t allow to write. I think that the problem is the init function (I have text areas outside the popups so i load (init) tinymce in my **"principal view"**)

Which could be the problem? How could i use tinyMCE in my "principal view" and popups?

Thanks in advance

NOTE: If you need my code please comment.

Comment: It's always a good idea to include your (relevant) code..

Comment: It's always a good idea to include a relevant question title..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post your code, it'll be easier to help you then.
But anyways, if you want to use tinyMCE with ROR, I recommend tinyMCE Hammer. Works great for me.

Here's the link : [TinyMCE Hammer](http://tinymcehammer.lanalot.com/)